# Program that checks if an array is a palindrome

Tags: c, string, palindrome

I'm trying to create a program that checks if a given array/string is a palindrome or not and its not working. The program just prints "0" on every given array, even on palindromes.

```
int main()
{

    char string[100]= {0};
    char stringReverse[100]= {0};

    int temp = 0;
    int firstLetter = 0;
    int lastLetter = 0;

    printf("Please enter a word or a sentence: ");
    fgets(string, 100, stdin);

    strcpy(stringReverse , string); // This function copies the scanned array to a new array called "stringReverse"

    firstLetter = 0;
    lastLetter = strlen(string) - 1;    //because in array, the last cell is NULL

    // This while reverses the array and insert it to a new array called "stringReverse"
    while(firstLetter < lastLetter)
    {
        temp = stringReverse[firstLetter];
        stringReverse[firstLetter] = stringReverse[lastLetter];

        stringReverse[lastLetter] = temp;

        firstLetter++;
        lastLetter--;
    }

    printf("%s    %s", stringReverse, string);

    if ( strcmp(stringReverse , string) == 0)
    {
        printf("1");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("0");
    }
}
```

Comment: Too much code for such a simple task.

Comment: i already have posted an answer to similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33806921/4487286) , you can easily adapt it to your needs

Answer (score 6):

Lets say we implement a simple fun to do that

```
int check_palindrome (const char *s) {
   int i,j;
   for (i=0,j=strlen(s)-1 ; i<j ; ++i, --j) {
      if (s[i] != s[j]) return 0; // Not palindrome
   }
   return 1; //Palindrome
}
```

I think this is far more simpler ;)

For the code posted in question:
Be aware of fgets(). It stops in the first '\n' or EOF and keeps the '\n' character.

So if you give **radar** for ex, the result string will be **"radar\n"**, which doesn't match with **"\nradar"**

Comment: There is no simpler way to do it than this. It's all you need. Don't forget to write a function to check for leading/trailing whitespace and you should be fine. If you have trouble with that, C actually has a function called `isspace()` which takes a char (technically it takes an int but just give it a char) and returns a non-zero value if it is a whitespace char such as \n, \t, \v, or a space. Returns 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

**The Problem:**

Let's say you enter the string `RACECAR` as input for your program and press enter, this puts a newline character or a `'\n'` in your buffer stream and this is also read as part of your string by `fgets`, and so your program effectively ends up checking if `RACECAR\n` is a palindrome, *which it is not*.

**The Solution:**

After you initialize `lastLetter` to `strlen(string) - 1` check if the last character in your string (or the character at the `lastLetter` index is the newline character (`\n`) and if so, decrease `lastLetter` by one so that your program checks if the rest of your string (`RACECAR`) is a palindrome.

```
lastLetter = strlen(string) - 1;    //because in array, the last cell is NULL

// Add these 2 lines to your code
// Checks if the last character of the string read by fgets is newline
if (string[lastLetter] == '\n')
    lastLetter--;
```

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` adds a '\n' at the end.
So if the user entered "aba", `string` contains "aba\n".
`reverseString` contains "\naba".

So it doesn't match.

After the fgets, add this code

```
int l = strlen(string) - 1;
string[l] = 0;
```

This will strip out the '\n' at the end before copying it to `reverseString`.

That aside, you can do this whole program inplace without the need of a second buffer or `strcpy` or `strlen` calls.

Comment: Detail: `fgets()` does not _add_ `'\n'`.  It simples saves it like all other input characters.  If user input was only 3 characters: `"aba"`, no <enter> key, and then `stdin` was closed, input would only be `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`.  `fgets()` does _add_ the terminating null character.  To safely remove the potential `'\n'`, consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/27729970#27729970

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues in your code:

- first you forgot the last closing brace `}`;
- then you forgot to remove the trailing `\n` (or maybe also `\r` under Windows) in `string`;
- you don't need to revert the string into a new string; a one-pass check is enough:

Here is a working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{

    char string[100]= {0};

    int temp = 0;
    int firstLetter = 0;
    int lastLetter = 0;

    printf("Please enter a word or a sentence: ");
    fgets(string, 100, stdin);

    firstLetter = 0;
    lastLetter = strlen(string) - 1;    //because in array, the last cell is NULL
    while ((string[lastLetter]=='\n')||(string[lastLetter]=='\r')) {
        lastLetter--;
    }

    // This while reverses the array and insert it to a new array called "stringReverse"
    temp = 1;
    while(firstLetter < lastLetter)
    {
        if (string[firstLetter] != string[lastLetter]) {
            temp = 0;
            break;
        }

        firstLetter++;
        lastLetter--;
    }

    if ( temp )
    {
        printf("1");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("0");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: `fgets(string, ...); int lastLetter = strlen(string) - 1; while ((string[lastLetter]...` is a hacker exploit.  It is fairly easy to have the first character of `string` to be `'\0'` and then `string[-1]` is UB.  Consider http://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2410359

Comment: @chux Yes, but this is only an adaptation of the post of the original poster; I merely changed the lines having issues. Of course other things could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this simpleway also.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[10], revString[10];
    printf("Enter string for reversing it...\n");
    scanf("%s", string);

    int stringLength = strlen(string);

    for(int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++, stringLength--)
    {
    revString[i] = string[stringLength - 1];
    }

    if(strcmp(string,  revString) == 0)
         printf("Given string is pelindrom\n");
    else
         printf("Given string is not pelindrom\n");
}
```

Comment: Suggesting `scanf("%s", tmp);` is about as good as coding `gets(tmp)`.  Recommend neither.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>`enter code here`
void fun(char *a);
 int main () 
 {    
     
      char p[100];
      char *s=p;
      
     printf("enter the string");
     scanf("%[^\n]",s);
     fun(s);
   
     
 }

void fun(char *a)
 { 
 
        
      if(*a && *a!='\n')
     {
      fun(a+1);
       
          putchar(*a);
       
      }
}
```

// use this approach better time complexity and easier work hope this helps